# open link in iframe of another page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iframe

In my rails app I have iframe as below.

```
<div class="flex-items">
  <iframe style="border:2px solid #CBD2D9;" height="800px" width="100%"  name="iframe_a"> </iframe>
</div>
```

I have below html in my home page.

```
<a href="/conversations/discussions" class="text-info">                  
    <span class="text-uppercase">
      <b><%= d["first"] + " " + d["last"] %></b>
    </span>           
</a>
```

These are in two different pages. I want to open link from home page, within iframe of another page. Can anyone help me?,

Comment: I think the solution to your need is to use a [partial](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials)

Comment: @JesusAlfonsoPintoDelgado can you explain how can I use it. I am new for rails.

Answer (score 0):

In your views... create a folder shared ROOT/app/views/shared

Example if what you have in the home is what you want to repeat inside the iframe

create a partial whit name _home.erb.html inside shared folder:

/app/views/shared/_home.erb.html

```
<a href="/conversations/discussions" class="text-info">                  
    <span class="text-uppercase">
      <b><%= d["first"] + " " + d["last"] %></b>
    </span>           
</a>
```

In your home.erb.html (only put)

```
<%= render "shared/home" %>
# with out underscore && extensions, only "shared/home"
```

In all Views where you find use this... repeat the code `<%= render "shared/home" %>`

example: replace iframe

```
<div class="flex-items">
  <div style="border:2px solid #CBD2D9;" height="800px" width="100%"> 
    <%= render "shared/home" %>
  </div>
</div>
```

you can create all partials as you need